# How to retrieve a list of subnets for launching a Fargate task?

Tags: c#, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I'm using the AWS SDK with C# in Visual Studio 2017, and have a prototype working which launches a Fargate service in ECS.  As part of the setup, you instantiate a `CreateServiceRequest` object which requires a `NetworkConfiguration.AwsVpcConfiguration` setting with `SecurityGroups` and `Subnets`.

```
var request = new CreateServiceRequest();

request.ServiceName = "myService";
request.TaskDefinition = "myTask";   // family[:revision] of the task definition to use
request.ClientToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");  // max 32 characters!
request.Cluster = "default";
request.DesiredCount = 1;
request.LaunchType = LaunchType.FARGATE;

request.DeploymentConfiguration = new DeploymentConfiguration
{
    MaximumPercent = 100,
    MinimumHealthyPercent = 50
};

// configure the network and security groups for the task
List<string> securityGroups = new List<string>();
securityGroups.Add("sg-123456");

List<string> subnets = new List<string>();
subnets.Add("subnet-9b36aa97");

request.NetworkConfiguration = new NetworkConfiguration
{
    AwsvpcConfiguration = new AwsVpcConfiguration
    {
        AssignPublicIp = AssignPublicIp.ENABLED,
        SecurityGroups = securityGroups,
        Subnets = subnets
    }
};
```

When I configure a service manually via the AWS Console, they display a list of subnets from which to choose.  So, I'm wondering how I might programmatically retrieve that list of subnets which are available in our VPC.

I'm searching their [SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/) for possible solutions, any pointers to their docs or examples is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at EC2Client, you'll find a lot of VPC-related APIs are associated with the EC2 service. Specifically check out `AmazonEC2Client.DescribeSubnets(DescribeSubnetsRequest)`, method documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/MEC2DescribeSubnetsDescribeSubnetsRequest.html):

### Request

[Amazon.EC2.Model.DescribeSubnetsRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TDescribeSubnetsRequest.html)

### Response

[Amazon.EC2.Model.DescribeSubnetsResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TDescribeSubnetsResponse.html)

Response contains a list of [Amazon.EC2.Model.Subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TSubnet.html) that you will retrieve string property `SubnetId` from, when deciding which subnet to pass on to your Fargate request.

### Example Usage (From the linked documentation):

```
var response = client.DescribeSubnets(new DescribeSubnetsRequest 
{
    Filters = new List<filter> {
        new Filter {
            Name = "vpc-id",
            Values = new List<string> {
                "vpc-a01106c2"
            }
        }
    }
});

List<subnet> subnets = response.Subnets;
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - EC2Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TEC2Client.html) - Search this document for 'DescribeSubnets' to find async variants of this SDK method.

Comment: ah, nice timing!  I was using the IAmazonECS interface, and had just begun looking at the AmazonECSClient section of their SDK documentation.  So it appears I'll need to go up another level to the EC2 layer.